# Modifying received packet src/dst using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to sniff my wifi for received packets. When I receive an ftp packet, I reverse the source and destination (Mac address, IP address and ports) and then send them back again.

However when I check wireshark, I find that the modified packet sent has an error "[Malformed Packet] [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]" although I deleted the checksums before I send the packet back. Below is the function I defined to modify received packet src/dst:

```
def modify_packet(pkt):
    source_mac_address = pkt[Ether].src
    destination_mac_address = pkt[Ether].dst
    destination_address = pkt[IP].dst
    source_address = pkt[IP].src
    destination_port = pkt[TCP].dport
    source_port = pkt[TCP].sport


    pkt[Ether].dst = source_mac_address
    pkt[Ether].src = destination_mac_address
    pkt[IP].dst = source_address
    pkt[IP].src = destination_address
    pkt[TCP].dport = source_port
    pkt[TCP].sport =  destination_port

    del pkt[IP].chksum
    del pkt[TCP].chksum

    send(pkt)
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scapy has not implemented Ethernet checksums because they are unpredictable: as said on [wireshark's doc](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet)

> Most Ethernet interfaces also either don't supply the FCS to Wireshark or other applications, or aren't configured by their driver to do so; therefore, Wireshark will typically only be given the green fields, although on some platforms, with some interfaces, the FCS will be supplied on incoming packets.

If you know a packet has a checksum however, it probably exists as a `Padding` Layer at the end of the Scapy packet you are processing. If that is the case, you can probably remove it without much issues.

You could try something like

```
if Padding in pkt:
    pkt[Padding].underlayer.remove_payload()
```

To remove it.

Another note: you need to use `sendp()` instead of `send()` when you are dealing with layer 2 packets (in this case: the ethernet frame)